# MAP bluetooth profile to transfer data

Tags: ios, bluetooth

​

I'm looking into MAP profile (on iOS) because is under standard profiles and you don't need MFi to use it.​

My question: is it possible to use MAP profile to transfer data (in messages)? or are you restricted to just messages, calls and emails? In other words - when I send data to phone over MAP profile is data accepted by any application or specifically my messages application (or phone application, or email application).

I hope I was clear :) thx​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own replay for purposes of "closing" the question.

I couldn't find the way of sending data over MAP - at least on iOS and event if I would manage to send it I'm almost certain that only specific application would be able to accept the data. So for example mail would be accepted by Mail application.